# var value into 2 decimal place value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create some simple code that can calculate the value of product that has been checked by checkbox form. The values are all in decimal (0.00) form. Javascript section is showing whole only. Can anyone assist how this can be done?

Here is the code

```js
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="iMac" id="<?php echo $rows2['id']; ?><?php echo $rows2['product_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $rows2['product_price']; ?>"></input>

    function computer() {

    var userMesssage = document.getElementById("userMesssage");

    var iMac = document.orderForm.iMac; // array of inputs
    var totalOrder = "";                // list all checked ids
    var totalCost = 0;                  // add values to calculate cost

    for (var i = 0; i < iMac.length; i++){
        if (iMac[i].checked) {
            totalOrder += iMac[i].id + " ,<br />";       // add ids separated by spaces
            totalCost += parseInt(iMac[i].value); // add value attributes, assuming they are integers
        }
    }

    // show total order and cost
    userMesssage.innerHTML = "<b>Your Budget</b>: <br />" + totalOrder + "<br />Total Budget: $" + totalCost;
    userMesssage.style.color = "#fff";
    }
```

Comment: numbers have a `toFixed` method - which return a String that you'll want to use

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .toFixed() function to convert into integer from decimal.

```
totalCost += (+(iMac[i].value).toFixed());
```

An additional `+` is added in front to convert string to number.

```js
console.log(+(Math.random()*10).toFixed());
```

Comment: `toFixed` needs an argument to specify the number of decimal places. It defaults to `0`.